# How to install an APK on an Android Tablet PC?

Tags: installation, apk, tablet-apps

I had one normal Android apk. It is working fine on my Android mobile. Now I want to install the same .apk on an Android tablet PC; is it possible? If possible, how can I install it?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to install an app:

1. Post it online (with something like Dropbox) and navigate to the
   URL in your tablet's browser
2. Use the marketplace if it's listed there
3. Use [adb install](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move) to do it

Make sure on the device that you have checked the checkbox listed at `Settings > Applications > Unknown Sources` if it is not in the Market. This will allow you to install non-Market apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can download apkinstaller from android market and install it. after that just put your application apk in your tablet sdcard, and click on apkinstaller you will get your apk here.   just click on your apk it will b installed .